# UIImageView rotation without moving Image

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Hi,
I want to rotate my `UIImageView` without moving the whole "png". No code is only to test what happens 
`_fanImage.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(45);`

It turns but the whole image moves. What can I do that this doesn't happen ?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Do you mean that the image view should rotate but the image which is set in the image view shouldn't?

Comment: No only the image should rotate not the whole ImageView because when ImageView rotates the image moves on an other place

Comment: I don't think this is possible. I don't know what happens when you draw the image directly onto a view and rotate the view. Should look the same as with an image view. But I still don't get what you mean by "the image moves on an other place".

Comment: Ok wait: Before rotation: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ba3zvk0xf0aoilc/Screenshot%202014-05-12%2019.59.36.png
After rotation: https://www.dropbox.com/s/a9xfndfsegzn6vl/Screenshot%202014-05-12%2019.59.41.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this.. You should rotate the `UIImage` rather than `UIImageView`.

```
- (UIImage *)imageWithTransform:(CGAffineTransform)transform {


    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.size.height, self.size.width);
    CGImageRef imageRef = self.CGImage;

    // Build a context that's the same dimensions as the new size
    CGContextRef bitmap = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL,
                                                self.size.width,
                                                self.size.height,
                                                CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(imageRef),
                                                0,
                                                CGImageGetColorSpace(imageRef),
                                                CGImageGetBitmapInfo(imageRef));

    // Rotate and/or flip the image if required by its orientation
    CGContextConcatCTM(bitmap, transform);



    // Draw into the context; this scales the image
    CGContextDrawImage(bitmap, rect, imageRef);

    // Get the resized image from the context and a UIImage
    CGImageRef newImageRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(bitmap);
    UIImage *newImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:newImageRef];

    // Clean up
    CGContextRelease(bitmap);
    CGImageRelease(newImageRef);

    return newImage;
}
```

Comment: Thanks I found a tutorial its similar now it works but now the UIImageView doesn't react on touches anymore.

Comment: Ok, but this is the first you've said about responding to touches, and you haven't shown any code related to handling touches.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean that you want your image view to rotate around it's center point. Is that right? If so, that's what a view should do by default.

You should do a search on "Translating, Scaling, and Rotating Views" in Xcode and read the resulting article.

Note that all of iOS's angles are specified in radians, not degrees.

Your sample images aren't really helpful, since we can't see the frame that the image view is drawn into. It's almost impossible to tell what your image views are doing and what they are supposed to be doing instead based on the pictures you linked from your dropbox.

A full 360 degrees is 2pi.

You should use

```
CGFloat degrees = 45;
CGFloat radians = degrees/180*M_PI;
_fanImage.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(radians);
```

That will fix the rotation amount for your code, but probably not the rotation position.

Comment: thanks no that doesn´t work, too.
I found a tutorial, now it works it's very similar to @iphonic ´s answer :)

Comment: Meaning what? What does "Doesn't work" mean? You need to better explain the problem you have before you say things like "it doesn't work" or "now it doesn't respond to touches".